# Making a Texture2D readable in Unity via code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I have some AssetBundles that I want to convert to .png image files.

They are Texture2D assets, but the problem is as they are not Read Enable, when 
I try to convert them to PNG with a

```
var _bytes = _texture2d.EncodeToPNG();
```

command, I get the following error message:

> *Texture 'name of a texture' is not readable, the texture memory can not be accessed from scripts. You can make the texture readable in the
>   Texture Import Settings.*

I really can't access the Texture Import Settings, as they come from asset bundles and everything is made with code.

Somebody has a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you make it readable with [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureImporter-isReadable.html)?

Comment: Thanks Aldour, but I don't think so. Textureimporter works when you import a texture in the editor, but the images have been already converted to Texture2D objects and stored as AssetBundles, so they don't go through the Textureimporter anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select texture in project, open inspector window, set texture type to "Advanced", toggle "Read and write enabled".

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, the textures are not in the project at all, I only have Assetbundles that have been created from Texture2D objects, so I can't make any edition in the Editor. The utility I'm making loads those Assetbundles in order to export again the images, so we can edit them in Photoshop.

Comment: You still can render unreadable texture to RenderTexture and then read it.

Comment: Good point, game development germ. I will try that workaround, thanks.

Comment: This is not a valid case for textures made with `new Texture2D(...)`. How can I read such textures, or I should work with Color[] before setting the pixels?

Comment: Textures created in runtime must be readable/writeable.

Comment: I am struggling with this as well. How would you render an unreadable texture to RenderTexture?

Comment: @DavidGuaita What if the texture is loaded from the server using `DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent`

Comment: I think the question is "Making a Texture2D readable in Unity via code" not "via Unity Inspector"

Answer (score 23):

Here's a working solution:

```
public static void SetTextureImporterFormat( Texture2D texture, bool isReadable)
{
    if ( null == texture ) return;

    string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath( texture );
    var tImporter = AssetImporter.GetAtPath( assetPath ) as TextureImporter;
    if ( tImporter != null )
    {
        tImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.Advanced;

        tImporter.isReadable = isReadable;

        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset( assetPath );
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: As this solution relies on AssetDatabase (which is in the UnityEditor namespace) this can only be used in the editor. It fails when building, though (The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found.)

Comment: sorry but this will only work in the Editor

Comment: @Schnodderbalken this script has to be placed in "Editor" directory.

Comment: One potential problem, after running this code the gameobject reference to this texture will throw a nullreferenceexception.